# Flash magic Alternative on Linux for LPC1227

Tags: arm, lpc, nxp-microcontroller

I am working on a custom board with LPC1227 and need to program it serially.
Flash magic is a Windows program to burn the firmware on the Chip serially. I tried making this work via wine but it does not communicate with the board. I also tried other Linux based ISP Programs for Linux (mxli and lpc21isp) but I think they do not work on LPC1227 Microcontroller as I did not get a response from the Microcontroller.

Further i also tried sending the commands as given in [AN11229.pdf](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN11229.pdf)

via cutecom and could perform the ISP Initialization with proper response. But I have no about burning a hex file via cutecom.

Is there any ISP utility for Linux that would do the job for me ?

Comment: I've used lpc21isp for 11xx, 12xx and 13xx chips before. While possible that it doesn't work for your 1227, it's not very likely. Try the newest version, see what it outputs.

Comment: Thank you so much!.. The latest version worked.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the lpc21isp's latest tree and compiled it. The current version is 1.97 and it works properly. Earlier I had Version 1.94 which did not work